# Google+ Remove Cover

Tags: google-plus

Is it possible to remove the profile cover once you've set one?
Basically, have it revert to the initial "default" one of that particular account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no option to remove it. You can re upload the original photo

https://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/profiles/defaultimage_bluegreen_940x180.png

Here it is before

[image: Before]

And After

[image: After]

The photo realigns perfectly

Comment: That said, there _is_ a gallery of generic images one can also use for the cover.

Comment: Thank you, Al. I thought about doing that, but it seems some get different colours of the same cover above.

Answer (score 0):

Go the album archive and delete the required photo.

There are options to remove the profile photo but no option is available for the cover photo. So you have to remove it that way.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the cover from Picasa web albums. It will set the cover to "some" default.

Same can be done with Profile picture.